# getting failed to create java virtual machine error everytime I try to open eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine

[image]

I have tried a variety of different solutions found on stack and other places on google and I keep getting the same error message every time I try to open eclipse.  It has been running fine for several years and then three days ago I shut it down.  Today I tried to reopened it and I keep getting the message. Here is the code from the Eclipse.ini file. I am using a Mac version 10.6.8. Here is a screen shot. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  -startup
  ../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
  --launcher.library
  ../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.100.v20110502
  -product
  org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: Is there anything specific in the error message besides "can't start VM"?

Comment: Nope, Just failed to create the Java Virtual Machine

Comment: Can you try uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: That is my nuclear option.  I am wondering if there is anything else

Comment: Have you patched Java to fix the [flashback malware issue](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5242)?  Also, sometimes Eclipse issues will clear up if you remove your workspace, I'd try that before the nuclear option.

Comment: I have tried the flashback for snow leopard and keep getting an error.  Wondering if that is the source of my problems.  Man I really do not want to take my mac in.  For removing workspace do you mean delete the workspace file?

Comment: How about a screenshot of the error when Eclipse won't launch?

Comment: I just added a screen shot of the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that Java isn't up to date. Go to Software Update on your mac and update Java. After trying everything else on other forums, this finally worked!
http://java.com/en/download/apple_manual.jsp?locale=en

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the line : **256m** which is after **--launcher.XXMaxPermSize**